# Change regional and language options in BATCH

Tags: batch-file, localization

How can I change the regional and language options in Windows XP and 7 using batch code?

I want to change the "Standards and formats" to Mexican Spanish with a .bat file.

Comment: full `ImportFile.reg` source code sample?

Comment: Have a look at DISM commands too:DISM Languages and International Servicing Command-Line Options https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh825081.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those settings are in the registry under `HKCU\Control Panel\International`

You can use reg.exe to make the changes manually. The easiest way to do that is to manually change your region and language to spanish (mexico) open a cmd window and type `reg query "HKCU\Control Panel\International"` which will show you the values as you want them. Then to modify them, use `REG ADD "HKCU\Control Panel\International" /t REG_SZ /v LocaleName /d es-Mx /f` for each value replacing what is after /v with the appropriate name and what is after /d with the appropriate value.

The other option is to just export the `HKCU\Control Panel\International` hive to a .reg file and just import it into the registry using `regedit /s ImportFile.reg`

You may need to refresh the registry after the import to see the changes. This usually involves a reboot but try adding the following as the last line in your batch file instead.             `RUNDLL32.EXE USER32.DLL,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters ,1 ,True`

Comment: And for **`Windows Server 2008 R2`** ?