# Batch: enforce language

Tags: output, locale, batch-processing

Is there any command that says **"Now in english, please"** to the computer?

I don't want to change the system locale like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689831/change-regional-and-language-options-in-batch), all I need is to change the language temporarily within the code execution.

---

Backstory:

I am writing a script to automatically report system informations to feed them into a database that should have been set years ago and maintained since then.

The problem is that `systeminfo.exe`, for example, returns english-labelled lines when run on my machine and czech-labelled lines on my colleague´s machine. On both machines the czech letters are misencoded. Both machines have same System Locale and Input locale (`cs;¬eçtina`), the first one is a Dell running Win10Pro and the second one is a Lenovo running Win7Pro SP1.

Luckily, I don't need to care about czech letters in a key part. Unluckily I need to parse the report to fetch data I actually need (5 lines out of 50+ lines) and there are very few notmisencoded lines.

Two lines from the report as a part of `systeminfo.exe` returns:

My machine returns:

```
System Locale:             cs;¬eçtina
Input Locale:              cs;¬eçtina
```

Colleague's machine returns:

```
Mˇstnˇ nastavenˇ syst‚mu:            cs;¬eçtina
N rodnˇ prostýedˇ:                   cs;¬eçtina
```

I wish them both return `System Locale` as a label.

Answer (score 0):

I dont really understand what you mean.
But try adding the following to the beginning of the batch script:

```
chcp 65001
```

This sets the default encoding to UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but this switch messed the output more rendering weird symbols as thousand separator.